# Laravel Vapoor on aws codepipeline

Tags: laravel, laravel-vapor

Laravel vapor is completely developed on aws platform but not used aws code pipeline to deploy codes. Has anyone tried aws code pipeline to deploy vapor codes?

I can deploy ubuntu server and install required PHP extensions and run vapor deploy staging command in aws codedeploy. Wondering is there any better way to deploy laravel vapor.

Comment: The way you're describing sounds pretty decent. What does "better" mean for you? Is there any particular "pain" you're experiencing with this?

Comment: maintaining laravel and php versions. otwell has handled it in forge but not in vapor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I made the below changes in the buildspec.yml file and used the ubuntu instance.

```
install:
    commands:
       - nohup /usr/local/bin/dockerd --host=unix:///var/run/docker.sock --host=tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 --storage-driver=overlay2 &
       - timeout 15 sh -c "until docker info; do echo .; sleep 1; done"
       #- command
      #- echo Logging in to Amazon ECR
  pre_build:
    commands:
       - docker run --name myvapor -d -e VAPOR_API_TOKEN=MY_VAPOR_API_TOKEN  --volume $(pwd):/~   --workdir /~ teamnovu/laravel-vapor
       - docker exec myvapor  vapor deploy staging
```